# Change android:drawableLeft on Button

Tags: android

I have the following button xml with an image on the left side.

I wonder how possible to change that image to something else when user clicks on it.

```
 <Button
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="24dp"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="Start"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:id="@+id/startBtn"
   android:textAllCaps="false"
   android:layout_weight="2"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_18dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a variable to check your **Button** is selected or not.

```
private int buttonState = 0;

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (buttonState % 2 == 0) {
               yourButton.setCompoundDrawables(R.drawable.ic_selected, null, null, null);
            } else {
               yourButton.setCompoundDrawables(R.drawable.ic_not_selected, null, null, null);
            }
            buttonState ++;
        }
    });
```

With **buttonState** variable you can follow the last state of your button.

Comment: Hi Emin, thanks for the answer, but questions is to implement a toggle behavior. Like you click first time, it will change to image2, and click again it will change back to image 1.